# Concatenar una variable PHP en una consulta MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, pdo

estoy haciendo una consulta `SQL`  en `PHP`  utilizando `MVC`. Estoy haciendo una función la cual tiene un parámetro y este se utiliza en la consulta `SQL`.  Este es el código y hasta este punto me funciona bien.

```
public function miFuncion($u){
  $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT T.tare_id AS tarea_id, TI.tick_codi AS codigo, TI.tick_nom AS nombre_ticket, PI.piez_nom AS pieza, T.num_pieza AS cantidad_piezas, PR.prod_nom AS producto,concat(US.usua_nom,' ',US.usua_ape) AS usuario , ES.esta_nom AS estado, EM.empr_nom AS cuenta, T.tare_asig AS fecha_de_asignacion, T.tare_entr AS fecha_de_entrega, MAX(HI.hist_cod) AS cantidad_ajustes
                                    FROM tarea T
                                    INNER JOIN pieza PI ON T.piez_id = PI.piez_id
                                    INNER JOIN producto PR ON T.prod_id = PR.prod_id
                                    INNER JOIN usuario US ON T.user_id = US.usua_id
                                    INNER JOIN ticket TI ON T.tick_id = TI.tick_id 
                                    INNER JOIN estados ES ON T.esta_id = ES.esta_id
                                    INNER JOIN empresa EM ON TI.empr_id = EM.empr_id
                                    INNER JOIN historial HI ON T.tare_id = HI.tare_id
                                    WHERE T.user_id = 11
                                    GROUP BY T.tare_id
                                    ORDER BY tarea_id ASC");
  $stm->execute();
  return $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

}
```

Cuando reemplazo en la linea del `WHERE` el valor de 11 por la variable `$u`
Este me arroja el siguiente error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY T.tare_id ORDER BY tarea_id ASC' at line 11

El valor del parámetro me esta llegando a la función,  lo he comprobado con un ´echo´.  Pero al reemplazar el valor del 11 por la variable $u la consulta ya no me funciona.

Comment: Tu variable `$u`, la cual **nunca** deberías pasar directamente a una consulta, produce una instrucción SQL extraña, errónea... podría ser incluso un intento de inyección de código malicioso mal elaborado para suerte tuya. Haz lo que te dice @shadow: usa consultas preparadas, cambiando `WHERE T.user_id = $u` por un marcador y pasándolo con `bindParam` o directamente en el `execute`. Para futuras preguntas, pon el código que falla, no el que funciona. Quizá haya más errores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas usando *PDO* no es correcto y si muy inseguro que pases la variable de manera directa a la query, en su lugar debes pasar el valor como un *marcador de nombre* en esta forma `:valor`

Entonces debes tenerlo así, por ejemplo:

```
$u = 10;
```

Ahora dentro de tu consulta mandalo llamar así:

```
$stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT T.tare_id AS tarea_id, TI.tick_codi AS codigo, TI.tick_nom AS nombre_ticket, PI.piez_nom AS pieza, T.num_pieza AS cantidad_piezas, PR.prod_nom AS producto,concat(US.usua_nom,' ',US.usua_ape) AS usuario , ES.esta_nom AS estado, EM.empr_nom AS cuenta, T.tare_asig AS fecha_de_asignacion, T.tare_entr AS fecha_de_entrega, MAX(HI.hist_cod) AS cantidad_ajustes
                                    FROM tarea T
                                    INNER JOIN pieza PI ON T.piez_id = PI.piez_id
                                    INNER JOIN producto PR ON T.prod_id = PR.prod_id
                                    INNER JOIN usuario US ON T.user_id = US.usua_id
                                    INNER JOIN ticket TI ON T.tick_id = TI.tick_id 
                                    INNER JOIN estados ES ON T.esta_id = ES.esta_id
                                    INNER JOIN empresa EM ON TI.empr_id = EM.empr_id
                                    INNER JOIN historial HI ON T.tare_id = HI.tare_id
                                    WHERE T.user_id = :u
                                    GROUP BY T.tare_id
                                    ORDER BY tarea_id ASC");
```

Posterior usamos `bindParam()` para indicarle el valor por el cual debe sustituir el marcador de nombre, de este modo

```
$stm->bindParam(':u', $u);
```

De este modo ayudas a minimizar los ataques de inyección SQL pues no pasas directo el valor que llega por parte del usuario a tu consulta SQL

Opcionalmente puedes indicar en el `bindParam()` el tipo de dato que se espera recibir, teniendo opciones como:

`PDO::PARAM_INT` Para valores enteros

`PDO::PARAM_STR` Para valores de tipo cadena de texto

Quedando de este modo

`$stm->bindParam(':u', $u, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Answer (score 1):

1. Este error **1064** se presenta por varias causas, entre ellas y mas común es por usar una palabra **reservada**.
2. También por usar mal un comando como escribir mal **FRON** *(cuando querías escribir **FROM**)* ó **UDDATE** *(cuando querías escribir **UPDATE**)*, pero si te funciona con el 11 quemado, este no es el caso.

Prueba renombrando el parámetro con: T.user_id = **$id_user** ó en comillas simples T.user_id = **'$id_user'**

Comment: que es `FRON` ? además del hecho de que recomendarle pasar valores dinámicos a la consulta es una mala práctica de seguridad

Comment: Estoy dando ejemplo de escribir mal los comando, mira UDDATE tambien esta mal, son ejemplos solamente.

Comment: @YoGo he actualizado su respuesta para dejar mas claro a qué te referías con FRON y UDDATE. Como recomendación, cuando coloques "valores incorrectos" explica cuál o cuáles serían los valores correctos.

Comment: Recomendaría que evites escribir respuestas basadas en suposiciones. El OP ha mostrado que en su código ha escrito `FROM` correctamente, no sé entonces por qué inventas lo del `FRON` o lo del `UDDATE`. En el sitio los esfuerzos son constantes porque quienes preguntan se basen en situaciones reales de su código, si eso es en las preguntas, no te digo nada de las respuestas. **Evita suposiciones**, por la buena calidad del sitio y para que la ayuda sea específica y eficaz.